# Not clear about Usage of change() function as described in the example - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just read this example here for Change() event, but didn't quite follow  double use of change() here. The docs says explains "Attaches a change event to the select that gets the text for each selected option and writes them in the div. It then triggers the event for the initial text draw."
Please elaborate the last line!!

```
   <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>change demo</title>
          <style>
          div {
            color: red;
          }
          </style>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
          <option>Chocolate</option>
          <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
          <option>Taffy</option>
          <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
          <option>Fudge</option>
          <option>Cookie</option>
        </select>
        <div></div>

        <script>
        $( "select" )
          .change(function () {
            var str = "";
            $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
              str += $( this ).text() + " ";
            });
            $( "div" ).text( str );
          })
          .change();
        </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select") // this line is the selector
    .change(function () {  // this line starts adding the change event handler
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $("div").text(str);
})
    .change();// this line then triggers that event handler (from the chained selector).
```

The same effect would be had from:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $("div").text(str);
});
$("select").change();
```

OR this:

```
$("select")
    .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $("div").text(str);
});
$("select").trigger('change');
```

WHY you would do the first is that it uses the chaining and thus does not have to select (find) the element for the selector multiple times.  It also ensures that your handler is fully added prior to it being triggered.

NOTE: Event handlers are executed when they are triggered, either manually by a user or from code such as this where this manually triggers that handler at that point.

NOTE: In jQuery, the empty `.change()` is a trigger and does not add a NEW function since there is nothing in there like in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It simply triggers the change event as a way to initialize the text on the div. Since all the logic is within the change listener. The listener reads all selected options out of the select and writes it on the div. However, the listener fires only when the change event occurs or if you trigger the event yourself. Think of the listener as an action to be performed. It's performed when the associated event occurs. The action in this case is to write the selected options into the div text.

Since we don't want an empty box from the beginning, we'll call the listener (the action) to do it for us, instead of rewriting the action.

It's also important to notice that .change will return the jQuery object from which it's being called. So you can chain it like this:

```
$('select').change(function() { /*do something*/ }).change(function() { /*doSomething else*/ }).change(); //and so on.
```